# Loop through PHP Array and display values in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an Array `$array` and want to create an html5 chart using the values of that array. For that purpose I use `chart.js`

The code I use looks like this (Unfortunately, I need to output the Javascript via PHP):

```
$chart = '
<script>
var data = {
    labels: ['."$array[0]".', '."$array[1]".', "..."],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Chart",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};
</script>';
print_r($chart);
```

That works fine so far, but the array gets updated with time to time and so should the chart. I figured out I would need a loop to do that but am not quite sure how to run the loop in the Javascript code. This doesnt work:

```
labels: ['.for ($i = 0, $i < count($array), $i++) {echo "$array[$i].','"}.'];
```

Comment: First of all, why are you not using the templating abilities of PHP?

Comment: The first time the script is sent to the browser with some data and this data gets rendered correctly. After that do you need to receive some other data from the server? It is quite unclear to me, do you mind elaborating?

Comment: Also, instead of sending all the script to the client you could `json_encode` the values you need to display and then use them in your script

Comment: I have a script which gets run everytime somebody visits a site and this script gets data from the database and stores it in an array which I then want to use in that javascript code what do you mean by elaborating (sorry I am new) :)

Comment: Check my answer, at first I couldn't understand your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to return the array printed. Actually in your code you can remove the echo.

Please be advised this is a quick hack and shouldn't be used. You should be using some templating function

```
function displayMe($ar){
     $res = '';
     for ($i = 0, $i < count($array)-1, $i++){
         $res .= '"'.$array[i].'",';
     }
     return $res . '"'.$array[count($array)-1] . '"';
}

$chart = '
<script>
var data = {
    labels: ['. displayMe($array).'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Chart",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};
</script>';
print_r($chart);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete solution, but it should help you out.

Use the templating abilities of PHP to make your life easier:

```
<?php 

// your code blah blah blah
// initialize $array, etc

?>
<script>
var data = {
  labels: [
    <?php
      for ($i = 0, $i < count($array), $i++) {
        echo $array[$i] . ",\n";
      }
    ?>
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "My Chart",
      fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
      highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
      highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }
  ]
};
</script>
<?php

 // continuation of your php code
 // blah di blah bla

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I can't check it out now though.
Instead of "unrolling" the array by yourself you could try like so:

```
$chart = '
<script>
var data = {
    labels: '.json_encode($array).',
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Chart",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};
</script>';
echo $chart;
```

basically `json_encode` encodes the php array into a javascript object, just what you need!

Also, `print_r` is not needed (print recursively), just use `echo` (or `print`)

Comment: Wow thats actually pretty neat. How can I get the values instead of the object because now it display "[object Object]"

Comment: `data.labels` is your array, inside you have your items. If you have other nested arrays they will be displayed as Object in the console.